# Switch between the keyboard layouts of the Xserver/xorg?

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout

I had added up English(US), Belgian(alternative), Tamil Keyboard layouts using the GUI.

How do I easily switch between these three layouts from terminal?

Comment: Answers on the Original question doesn't works for me.I'm running 13.10.But the below answer makes  to easily switch between different keyboard layouts which we are added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu 13.10, if your keyboard layouts are *exactly* in this order: English (US), Belgian (alternative), Tamil and:

- if you have set English (US) keyboard layout, then:

  - to change to Belgian (alternative) keyboard layout, use:

    ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'be+oss'), ('xkb', 'in+tam'), ('xkb', 'us')]"
    ```
  - to change to Tamil keyboard layout, use:

    ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'in+tam'), ('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'be+oss')]"
    ```
- if you have set Belgian (alternative) keyboard layout, then:

  - to change to Tamil keyboard layout, use:

    ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'be+oss'), ('xkb', 'in+tam'), ('xkb', 'us')]"
    ```
  - to change to English (US) keyboard layout, use:

    ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'in+tam'), ('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'be+oss')]"
    ```
- if you have set Tamil keyboard layout, then:

  - to change to English (US) keyboard layout, use:

    ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'be+oss'), ('xkb', 'in+tam'), ('xkb', 'us')]"
    ```
  - to change to Belgian (alternative) keyboard layout, use:

    ```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'be+oss'), ('xkb', 'in+tam')]"
    ```

Obs: These commands *works only in Ubuntu 13.10* (and maybe later versions).

Answer (score 2):

You can change keyboard layouts using `setxkbmap`. This is guaranteed to work with any version of Ubuntu. To change to us layout:

```
setxkbmap us
```

To change to tamil:

```
setxkbmap in+tam
```

to change to Belgian:

```
setxkbmap be+oss
```

The preferences will be kept until you close your session or restart the system.

Comment: That doesn't actually seem to be the case - yes, you can change the layout, but ubuntu will reset it after a short period of time, in my experience (only 13.10 and up).

Comment: @Fake51 he doesn't want to do the change permanent as far I read the question.

Comment: Presumably more than 1 minute or first window switch - that's all the persistence I get.